# C++ undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit@0`

Tags: c++, makefile, glew

Note: I have seen the post about the person having this problem in the C language because the glew.c script was not loading for him, I don't think that is my problem.  From following the exact steps on the GLEW documentation website as closely as possible (and in which I saw no mention of a requirement to add a file called glew.c) I've setup glew with MinGW and extracted the dll's and libs to the appropriate folders yet at compile time I get this message:

```
undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit@0`
```

Here is my main file main.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow("Glew Test");
    GLenum err = glewInit();

    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        cout << "Something effed up";
    }

    cout << "Awwwwwwwwhhhhh Yeeeeeeeaaaaah!!!";

return 0;
}
```

And here is my MakeFile:

```
MY_LIBS = -lglut32 -lglew32 -lopengl32 
glewex:
    g++ -g main.cpp -o glewex $(MY_LIBS)
```

Any ideas as to why I get this error?

Comment: Try moving the `-lopengl32` to the front of the list.

Comment: new Makefile line: MY_LIBS = -lopengl32 -lglut32 -lglew32 gives same error

Comment: Are you trying to statically link to these libraries? If so, try `#define GLEW_STATIC` before including `glew.h`

Comment: the error is the same just without the "_imp__" part

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you insist on linking to this library externally? It causes way more trouble than it is worth.

Add `glew.c` to your project. Just compile it in with the rest of your source files. As long as you `#define GLEW_STATIC` it will work fine. Problem solved.

Even if you succeed at linking it to the library, you are then bound to one specific architecture/build/version. If you just include `glew.c` you will be free to build the project virtually anywhere.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw You mean, include `glew.h` in your project? not `glew.c` as such?

Comment: Nope. I mean `glew.c`. I am suggesting you actually compile glew as part of your project. Of course, the rest of your code will `#include "glew.h"`, but that's not the topic here.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. glewGetErrorString and glewInit were being reported as undefined for me. couldn't track the problem.

then i remembered i had downloaded the 64 bit version of glew while free-glut and everything else i downloaded was  32bit

so re-downloaded glew for 32 bit. and everything worked perfectly! hope that helps someone in the future.